# Remove character from entire website using javascript

Tags: javascript, squarespace

Is it possible to remove a character from an entire website using javascript? Ideally pure javascript without needing to link a library. I'm working with a site that uses an arrow (→) on some of the buttons and links that i'd like to get rid of. The template is locked so I need to hack my way there. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple loop to find and replace arrow character in all links and buttons.

```js
/* Remove arrow from linkes */

var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i=0; i<allLinks.length; i++) {
    allLinks[i].text = allLinks[i].text.replace('→', '');
}

var allButtons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for(var i=0; i<allButtons.length; i++) {
    allButtons[i].innerText = allButtons[i].innerText.replace('→', '');
}
```

```html
<button name="btn_arrow">
  Button arrow →
</button>

<a href="#">Link → Arrow</a>
```

Comment: This worked great, except on Squarespace it seemed to affect images so I targeted by the class of the links/buttons instead. Thanks!